# How to use the result of a fetch call in a for loop of fetch calls in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, fetch-api

I am making a nearby search fetch call to the google maps API for a list of locations based on a user's input. The response does not include several pieces of basic information like a phone number or a link to the location's website. It does, however, contain a places ID field which the documentation encourages you to use to make a second call to get the remaining details.

I'm a newbie and so async await/promise.all() is still something I'm struggling to grok and the many implementations I've tried to adapt from other questions have not worked, so my head's starting to spin.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
fetch(googleMapsApi).then(response => response.json).then(data => {
  for (let i = 0; i <data.results.length; i++) {
    //shove some data onto page where applicable from this first call
    fetch(data.results[i].PlaceID_apiCall).then(response => response.json).then(data => {
    //shove the rest of the relevant data onto the page
    }
  }
}
```

This is clearly not working due to the synchronous nature of Javascript, but I'm too dumb to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: What exatcly do not work? This code may work well in some cases.
If you need to apply changes once, then you should use `Promise.all` to array of `fetch` requests

Comment: smth like - `Promise.all(data.results.map(res =>  fetch(res.PlaceID_apiCall).then(r => r.json()))).then(allData => /* doSometh */ )`

Comment: As I see you do not call `json` method in your example and just return it

Comment: `response.json` is incorrect.  It should be `response.json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use asynchronous function for fetch api.

```
const res = await fetch(googleMapsApi);
for (let i = 0; i <res.data.results.length; i++) {
    //shove some data onto page where applicable from this first call
    const cellRes = await fetch(data.results[i].PlaceID_apiCall);
    //shove the rest of the relevant data onto the page
}
```

We can use `new promise` function instead of `await/async`.

Comment: This sorted it! Thank you so much for helping me (kiiiinda) grasp async/await stuff. I was so close but I couldn't adapt what I was seeing to my code, super appreciate you taking the time to help out!